# GitLab build docker on kubernetes runner

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, pipeline

I've just connected my gitlab account to an existing kubernetes cluster. Then I generated a private runner on the cluster. In the pipeline, I wanted to build a docker image, but I always get the error, can't connect to the docker daemon. I realized, probably because `privileged` is not true, but I can't really find the solution, how can I create the private runner as a `privileged` one.

edit: I created the runner through the gitlab GUI, https://gitlab.com/ORG/PROJ/-/clusters/CLUSTER_ID?tab=apps and there I clicked the install runner button.

Comment: Hi @Ghostika, How did you create your private runner? There is an [example](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/policy/security-context/) how to add `securityContext:
        privileged: true
` to your pod. If you used [gitlab runner helm chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html#additional-configuration) then you can set the `runners.privileged: true` in values.yaml.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're looking for [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#runner-configuration). There are three methods to enable the use of docker build and docker run during jobs. There is an [example](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#define-keywords-in-the-configuration-toml) of how to set that in config.toml.

Comment: This doesn't help at all, I have deployed the runner into the cluster, should I ssh into that pod?